# How to create an if statement with an array in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement

I am trying to make an app that uses a login system. I have created an array for both the usernames and the passwords. But I need to test if the password is correct or not. How can I create an if statement that tests for values that are inside of an array? Here is my code in case you need it.

```
import UIKit

var namesArray = [String]()
var passWordArray = [String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var username = "Ege"
    var password = "Gürkan"
    var trueFalse = true

    @IBOutlet weak var idTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var trueWrongLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if idTextField.text == "Ege" && passwordTextField.text == "Gürkan" {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("geçiş", sender: self)

        } else {

            trueWrongLabel.text = "Wrong id/pw"

            idTextField.resignFirstResponder()

            passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()

            trueWrongLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

            idTextField.text = nil

            passwordTextField.text = nil

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(namesArray, forKey: "nameArray")

        var recalledNameArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("nameArray")! as NSArray

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(passWordArray, forKey: "passWordArray")
        var recalledPassWordArray: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("passWordArray")        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }        
}
```

In the line that says: `if isTextField.text == "Ege"`
I want to test if there is a value for what has the user just entered in the textfield. How can I do it?

PS: I am very new to programming in general so please don't use complicated terms while explaining

Comment: Load the passwords into a dictionary with the username as the key. Then simply use the username to retrieve the password - if you get nil or a value that doesn't match the login fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is beginning programming stuff.

There are lots of ways to do this.

One straightforward way would be to create a struct that contains a name property and a password property. Then create an array of the structs. When the user enters a username and password, use a filter command to find the structure that contains the matching username, and then check to see if the password is correct.

If you're not comfortable with the Swift filter function (I haven't used it yet myself) then you could also loop through the array yourself looking for matches.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using Array for userName and Array for Password?
How can you know if that password for that userName?
I advice you to use Dictionary it is the best solution for you.
so one Dictionary for username and password and the values will be:

```
key:value
Ege:Gürkan
```

and the code will be:

```
for (key,value) in dic
{
if (key == idTextField.text && value == passwordTextField.text)
{
println("true")
}
}
```

I hope this is what you want!.